# how to nest lists in ionic 4 without it looking a complete mess?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Having problems trying to nest lists, I expected them to be inset the further down they go, but instead I've got a complete mess as you can see in the screenshot below.

Here's the code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div *ngIf="categories && categories.length > 0; then validContent else noContent"></div>
  <ng-template #validContent>
    <p>Please select the categories you wish to receive content for.</p>
    <form (ngSubmit)="processForm($event)" id="userForm" class="ssp__form">
      <ion-list lines="none" no-padding>
        <ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let category of categories">
          <ion-label>{{ category.name }}</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox [name]="category.slug" [(ngModel)]="submissionData[category.term_id]"></ion-checkbox>
          <ion-list inset="true" style="width:100%;" lines="none" no-padding *ngIf="category.children.length > 0">
            <ion-item *ngFor="let subCategory of category.children">
              <ion-label>{{ subCategory.name }}</ion-label>
              <ion-checkbox [name]="subCategory.slug" [(ngModel)]="submissionData[subCategory.term_id]"></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-button type="submit" style="width:100%;" color="primary" expand="block">Save Categories</ion-button>
    </form>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #noContent>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px;">No Categories Found.</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p style="text-align: center">There are no categories for you to read at this time.</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ng-template>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add on your post an example picture or drawing of the result visual that you expect?.

Comment: Can you show your object? I'm trying to follow the inconsistencies with the data displayed.

Comment: I’ll post these things you both requested tomorrow morning as I’m not on a computer.